# using .off function for multiple event handlers on a single selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, live, jquery-on

I have a code in which I have attached multiple event-handlers to a single selector using .on function of jquery

```
$(document).on({

     mouseenter: function() {
            console.log("handle enter");

        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            console.log("handle leave");

        }, 
        click: function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        }
},'.handle');
```

Now I want to remove all this event-handlers. I know this can be achieved using .off in the following way

```
$(document).off("mouseenter",".handle");
$(document).off("mouseleave",".handle");
$(document).off("click",".handle");
```

However my concern is I just want to use .off function only once and achieve the above.
How can I do this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just seperate the events by spaces, see the 2nd description of the .off function here: http://api.jquery.com/off

```
$(document).off("mouseenter mouseleave click",".handle");
```